# Stationarity of the sum of an ARMA processes

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

I've seen somewhat similar questions, but nothing that is quite like what I am concerned with currently.

Given that $ X_t=0.3X_{t-1}+e_{1t}+0.3e_{1,t-1} $ and $z_t=X_t+X_{t-1}$ ; is $z_t$ (weakly) stationary and/or invertible?

So,  I've tried to do this using the stationarity conditions, starting with a mean independent of time.

Note: $e_{1t}$~$WN(0,1)$

$$z_t=0.3X_{t-1}+0.3X_{t-2}+e_{1t}+1.3e_{1,t-1}+0.3e_{1,t-2}$$

Take expectation:

\begin{align*}E(z_t)&=E(0.3X_{t-1}+0.3X_{t-2}+e_{1t}+1.3e_{1,t-1}+0.3e_{1,t-2})
%
\\&=0.3E(X_{t-1})+0.3E(X_{t-2}) 
\\&= 0.3E(z_{t-1})
\end{align*}
And what I initially though is that because $z_t$ is dependent on time (due to the lags) then it is non-stationary. But I realised that this means that any model with an AR lag would be non-stationary, so my interpretation here is clearly incorrect.

Using the Unit root method:

Given that $z_t=X_t+X_{t-1}$,

\begin{align*}
z_t&=0.3X_{t-1}+0.3X_{t-2}+e_{1t}+1.3e_{1,t-1}+0.3e_{1,t-2}
\\
&=0.3(X_{t-1}+X_{t-2} )+e_{1t}+1.3e_{1,t-1}+0.3e_{1,t-2}
\\
&=0.3z_{t-1}+e_{1t}+1.3e_{1,t-1}+0.3e_{1,t-2}
\end{align*}
From here I can find the AR and MA polynomials. However, I am unsure if this method will provide correct results given the unchanged error terms..

My two questions

1. Is the working out I have done for the stationarity conditions methods correct? Because, it implies that any model with any ar lags will be non-stationary.
2. Can I simply use the unit root method after writing the equation in terms of $z_t$ to find stationarity/invertability?

Comment: Advise: if you have seen similar questions but not quite like what you are concerned with currently, refer to these questions.

Comment: Your MA polynomial has a root on the unit circle so $\{z_t\}$ does not admit a stationary solution. I do not understand what you mean by "*if this method will provide correct results given the unchanged error terms*"; the unit root method is exactly what you want to use to say something about stationarity of your process!

Comment: @Therkel Sorry, when I said similar questions, they were not similar enough to the extent that I could utilise them. I'll be a bit clearer also: My main issue is that my lecturer told me that it would not be possible with the unit root method and I could probably check if the mean is independent of time. I disagree with him on this.. I will update the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1.

Your work is correct but intermediate. You do not know anything about the expectation of $z_{t-1}$ (yet). However, if you reiterate a couple of times, you may realize that $z_t$ can be written on the form

$$
z_t = e_t + 2(\phi+1) e_{t-1} + 2(\phi + 1) \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \phi^j e_{t-1-j}
$$
for $\phi = 0.3 (<1)$. To show that the process is a mean-zero process, it suffices to show that
$$
2(\phi + 1) E\left[
 \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \phi^j e_{t-1-j}
\right] = 0.
$$
By a dominated convergence argument, using that $\phi<1$, we may interchange sum and expectation, giving the result.

To show that the autocorrelation function is independent of time, follow similar arguments.

### 2.

The problem with using the unit root method in this case is that the MA polynomial has a root on the unit disc $S = \{z \in \mathbb C : \lvert z \rvert = 1\}$, so the method is inconclusive.

Comment: For the process to be invertible, it suffices that the polynomials do not have common roots and that the MA-polynomial has roots outside the unit sphere, which is not the case here.